# I don't want box in ContourPlot3D in mathematica. Boxed->False does not work properly

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

ContourPlot3D in mathematica produces plot inside a box. When I set "Boxed -> False", it does not work properly, boxes do not disappear completely. plz help, I am in hurry, don't scold. Code I am using to generate a sphere:

`Show[ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 25, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}], 
 Boxed -> False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add one more thing: `Axes -> False`.
This is working
`ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 25, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]`